# Wrong mouse cursor during drag

Tags: css, drag-and-drop, web-component

I am implementing drag and drop on a polymer element. The element only consists of a simple div which is shaped like a diamond. When I am dragging the element, the drag-image turns into an octagon.

Here is the link to the JSbin : http://jsbin.com/yohohoba/4/edit

This might not even be related to web components and polymer. Might be a simple CSS issue. Any idea what might be causing this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: This looks like an interesting clipping bug with the CSS transform applied to the element and the drag (ghost) image that the browser creates. The same behavior happens with out Polymer: http://jsbin.com/bahazone/2/edit

Comment: Thanks ebidel. It worked by wrapping the div in another div of a bigger size. This would prevent the internal div from getting clipped by the bounding box. Here is the corrected code: http://jsbin.com/paqafode/1/edit